# Windows git "bad file descriptor" while commiting on OES Network Share

Tags: windows-7, git, cygwin, network-shares

Upfront: I don't have much experience with Windows and hardly any with coorporate networks.

I'm trying to use git for version control during the development of my software. The company I work for is mostly hardware based, so they don't seem to have this usecase very often. I do have to use Windows 7, so I installed the Windows version of git and chose "Make git available through the Git Bash", which does not add the git binaries to the Windows PATH but rather has a emulated UNIX environment (I believe cygwin) and shell. This is what I wanted to use.

The company also uses OES (Open Enterprise Server) by Novell to manage user accounts. That means we have generic Windows logins, but need to login to the OES server again after Windows login. This mounts a couple of Network Shares, including our own personal storage and proxy servers etc.

Since I do have to save my code on the network drive I also want to keep the git there. Managing the git on the local machine and copying the code to the network drive is not an option since I sometimes have to switch machines and generally its inconvenient and error prone. If I forget it, it would not be backuped.

Adding files to staging in git works fine, but when I try to commit, I get the error message

```
fatal: cannot update the ref 'HEAD': unable to append to '.git/logs/HEAD': Bad file descriptor
```

which I think has to to with the way Git Bash maps paths and how the network shares are mapped in this process.

A coworker claims to have succsessfully committed on a network share, but he's using Windows 10. I'm not sure, if git is using the new native Bash emulation then.

Is there any way to use git in this scenario?

Comment: What user are you running the git bash as? The user you login with or the novell user? It could be a permission issue.

Comment: That sounds plausible. `whoami` returns the Windows user. How can I log into the git bash with the Novell user?

Comment: You probably can't from within git. You'd need to start the git bash as that user. Windows has a default "run as" feature but I'm not sure whenever that works with Novell or not. It's a bit unusual that you wouldn't just use it in place of an AD. It's interesting that other software works fine. Bad file descriptor could also mean that for some reason the descriptor was discard.